# Div padding not disappearing; white border

Tags: html, css, padding, margins

```css
#page-container {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
}
#header {
  background-color: #f9f8e5;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

  <div id="header">
    <center>
      <br>
      <a href="index.html">
        <img src="images/logo.png">
      </a>
    </center>
  </div>

</div>
```

Just a quick one, and the solution is probably somewhat obvious and is eluding me, essentially there is a border around my container div for my website, margins, padding and borders are all set to 0 so why the border is still there i have no idea. The background colour fill is on the 'header' div, and from this I can see the evident white lines either side of the div. Any help is appreciated, code below.

CSS:

```
#page-container 
{
position:absolute;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
border: 0px;
}

#header 
{
background-color: #f9f8e5;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
margin-top: -10px;
padding: 0px;
border: 0px;
width: 100%;
height: 200px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="container">

        <div id="header">
        <center>
        <br>
        <a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png"></a>
        </center>
        </div>

<REST OF WEBPAGE>

</div>
```

Comment: if it's live can you post the link here?

Comment: To be honest, [I don't see any border](https://jsfiddle.net/yfvj6xod/1/).

Comment: Can you modify the snippet to show the minimal, complete, verifiable example? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<body>` element has margin set by default in browsers. Set `body { margin:0; }` and you shouldn't have margins anymore.

Comment: This is a winner, didn't realise I had to set the body to have 0 margins too. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

css

```
body {
  margin: 0px;
}
#page-container 
{
position:absolute;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
border: 0px;
}

#header 
{
background-color: #f9f8e5;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
margin-top: -10px;
padding: 0px;
border: 0px;
width: 100%;
height: 200px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ozbkr3sL/

of course you didn't provide full code to the page, but this css should help.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the color and properties you want for the body itself and not just the container. Put in a different color in the background to test it out. From the snippet you posted this is the best I can see. If you had a full link that would've helped.

`body{
    margin:0;
}`

```
body{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    color: yellow;
```

}